# Create new records based on primary key of different table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say I have two tables called `users` and `user_profiles`

`user_profiles` is empty without any rows, meanwhile `users` table has about 10-20k records.

**I want to create empty records for `user_profiles` based upon `users` primary key**

for question sake,

lets assume that

my `users` table has

`id` `name` `email`

my `user_profiles` table has

`id` `user_id` `data`

Is it possible to do strictly via SQL without involving any server-side script?

The end outcome, whatever amount of users I have, there should be rows of user_profiles matching this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following provided that your tables are structured properly with ALLOW NULL and `auto_increment` for `user_profiles` properties.

```
INSERT INTO user_profiles (user_id)
SELECT id FROM users
```

Comment: you are welcome - please tick as answered if it worked.

Comment: a quick question, is it possible if i want to do for two column whereby it should be like `INSERT INTO user_profiles (created, user_id) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), SELECT id FROM users)` ?

Comment: Give it a try and let me know if doesn't work.. No harm in trying yourself first :)

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work. `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id FROM users)' at line 1 `

Comment: TRY `INSERT INTO user_profiles (created, user_id)
SELECT CURRENT_DATE(), id FROM users`

Comment: Works great. Thanks, will accept your answer once timer is up. Thanks again